# Stuck in making angularjs filter based on or operator logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view:

```
 <tr>
     <td>
         <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="Active" checked ng-click="sort('false','false','false')">Active
              <span class="label label-success">{{totalActive}}</span>
         </label>
     </td>

     <td>
         <label class="radio-inline">
             <input type="radio" name="Active" ng-click="sort('true','','true')">Archieve
             <span class="label label-warning">{{appliedJob.length-totalActive-totalClosed}}</span>
         </label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <label class="radio-inline">
             <input type="radio" name="Active" ng-click="sort('','true','')">Closed
             <span class="label label-warning">{{totalClosed}}</span>
         </label>
     </td>
 </tr>

 <tr data-dir-paginate="item in appliedJob|orderBy:'AppliedDate':true|filter:{HiredAnother:filterText, Closed:Closed,Withdraw:w}|itemsPerPage:5">
```

MY JS Function:

```
$scope.filterText = false;
$scope.Closed = false;
$scope.w = false;


$scope.sort = function (key,c,w) {
    $scope.filterText = key;
    $scope.Closed = c;
    $scope.w = w;

}
```

What i want is that if Withdraw is false it will go on `Archieve` (no matter whether `HiredAnother` is true/false ). But in the filter it it goes on `Archieve` list only `HiredAnother =true` and `Withdraw=true`. 
How can i make or(||) operator in ng-repeat filter?

Clear my want:

```
Active-->HiredAnother=false,Closed=false, Withdraw=false
Archieve-->HiredAnother=true/false,Closed=false, Withdraw=false/true(HiredAnother and Withdraw- must be false at least one)
Closed-->HiredAnother=true/false,Closed=true, Withdraw=false/true
```

=================Upated with Expected result==========================

```
 <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="Active" checked ng-click="sort('ac')">Active
                        <span class="label label-success">{{totalActive}}</span>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="Active" ng-click="sort('ar')">Archieve


                        <span class="label label-warning">{{appliedJob.length-totalActive-totalClosed}}</span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="Active" ng-click="sort('cl')">Closed
                        <span class="label label-warning">{{totalClosed}}</span>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>

<tr data-dir-paginate="item in appliedJob|orderBy:'AppliedDate':true|filter:myFilter|itemsPerPage:5">


 //Filter based on radio button
$scope.myFilter = function (i) {
    return i.HiredAnother == false && i.Withdraw == false && i.Closed == false; //Active
};

$scope.sort = function (term) {

    if (term == 'ac') {
        $scope.myFilter = function (i) {
            return i.HiredAnother == false && i.Withdraw == false && i.Closed == false; //Active
        };
    }

    else if (term == 'ar') {
        $scope.myFilter = function (i) {
            return i.HiredAnother == true || i.Withdraw == true && i.Closed == false; //Arcieve
        };
    }
    else if (term == 'cl') {
        $scope.myFilter = function (i) {
            return i.Closed == true; //Arcieve
        };
    }
}
//Filter based on radio button END
```

Comment: are you using this https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination?

Comment: yes. Why ? Has it any relation with my want?

Comment: Info for help you, and pepople who try know where is exact to find API to if is possible

Comment: @basarat     Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using custom filter function that is called for each appliedJob.

```
<tr data-dir-paginate="item in appliedJob | filter: myCoolFilter">
```

and the function (have a look at [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))

```
$scope.myCoolFilter(value, index, array) {
    // change here according to your logic
    return $scope.filterText || $scope.Closed; 
}
```

Comment: But how can i do that using click event in radio button?

Comment: As `$scope.filterText`, `$scope.Closed`, etc changes, the list gets updated automatically thanks to digest cycle. I assume you already know how angularjs works.